# Web mapping API popularity

Tags: web-mapping, api, statistics

Are there any online statistics for the popularity/usage of web mapping APIs? A diagram would be sufficient, if it can be published in a paper. I have only found one source: https://trends.builtwith.com/mapping.

The problem with this source is, the license states that it cannot be published.

> You may view, download for caching purposes only, and print pages from the website, provided that:
>
> (a) you must not republish material from this website (including republication on another website), or reproduce or store material from this website in any public or private electronic retrieval system;
>
> (b) you must not reproduce, duplicate, copy, sell, resell, visit, or otherwise exploit our website or material on our website for a commercial purpose, without our express written consent;

Are there any citable sources out there for web mapping trends? Or did I misunderstand the conditions, and it can be published with proper citing?